# Make component link fields inline editable

Tags: experience-manager, 2013, razormediator

I'm working on a Razor template to display a kind of samll FAQ section. Each item of this FAQ (composed by a question and an answer in rich text fields) is added to the FAQ list as a component link and I would like to make it inline editable with Experience Manager.

I can make the list itself editable, so an editor can add or remove components and of course, I can make editable the general list fields but, is possible to make the linked component fields also editable?

I have tried with:

```cs
@RenderComponentField("componentLinkListField[" + counter + "].question")
```

And also with:

```
<tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLinkListField[@counter].question"></tcdl:ComponentField>
```

And even something like:

```
<tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLinkListField.question" index="@counter"></tcdl:ComponentField>
```

And a lot of variants of these examples... But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan for your time.

We have just contacted SDL and for now it's not possible. I missed a detail, we are working with Tridion 2013 and looks like this feature will be delivered for SP1.

Comment: No problem.  I guess that it is the `{'ID' : '{0}',` part that isn't implemented for 2013 yet.  It may be worth noting that this solution should work for Tridion UI Update for 2011.  I have updated the tags on your question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think that this is covered in the [Making subfields of embedded multivalue fields editable](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_531D916B066D4CD78661EB29BA33E2C3) section of the online documentation (login required).

Something like the following may work:

```
@@RenderComponentField("componentLinkListField[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].question", 0)@@
```

This should produce the following output (for the first question):

```
<span id="_SE_FLD" _SE_FLD="tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:componentLinkListField[1]/custom:HouseNumber[1]">
```

-

### Update [27/06/2013]

It looks like this is a known issue.  For example, some additional functions are given on the Tridion Practice site [here](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates).

It appears that there is a workaround for this that allows you to output the necessary Experience Manager / UI code (a HTML comment used on the front-end) just above the field that you want to make editable.
E.g.
`<!-- Start Component Field: {{'ID' : 'tcm:99-1234', 'XPath' : 'tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:question[1]'}} -->`

To do this you could write a Razor Helper Function that takes the tcmId of the Component and the name of the field.  E.g.

```
@helper OutputComponentLinkXmCode(string fieldName, string componentTcmId) {
   IdentifiableObject component = TridionHelper.Engine.GetObject(componentTcmId);
   @String.Format("<!-- Start Component Field: {{'ID' : '{0}', 'XPath' : 'tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:{1}[1]'}} -->", component.Id, fieldName);
}
```

You could then call this as follows:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Fields.componentLinkListField; i++) {
    <div class="question">@OutputComponentLinkXmCode("question",@componentLinkListField[i].ID)@Fields.componentLinkListField[i].Fields.question</div>

    <div class="answer">@OutputComponentLinkXmCode("answer",@componentLinkListField[i].ID)@Fields.componentLinkListField[i].Fields.answer</div>
}
```

I think that the field has to be wrapped in an outer HTML element (hence the `Div` in the code sample).

You could also extend the Razor function to multivalued fields (in the inner Component) by passing in the index (currently hardcoded to `[1]`).

This also assumes that the Root Element of your inner Q&A Component is still `Content` too.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but in this scenario the field is not an embedded field but a Component Link one, with multivalue allowed.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Looks awsome, thanks! I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work. Writing out '<!-- Start Component Field: {{'ID' : 'tcm:0-00-0', 'XPath' : 'tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:question[1]'}} -->' (as a generic example) results in the Experience manager UI obviating the ID parameter and searching for a question field in the current component instead of the linked one. I will continue digging on it...

Comment: What happens if you hardcore the tcmId?  Does UI still ignore it?