# How to use Site Edit for Embedded Schema Field and Multi Value Field

Tags: 2013, siteedit

We are using SDL Tridion 2013.  In Site Edit I want to edit an Embedded Schema Field and Multi Value Field. How would I do that?

We are using C# templating to render output. For simple text field to be edit in Site Edit  I'm using  `<tcdl:ComponentField name="FieldName">html of the field</tcdl:ComponentField>`

Example

```
rtnValue.AppendLine("<tcdl:ComponentField name=\"PageHeading\">");
rtnValue.AppendLine("<h2 class=\"page-title\">" + GetSingleStringValue("PageHeading", pfd).ToUpper() + "</h2></tcdl:ComponentField>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you tell us what you have already tried please?

This scenario sounds very similar to this: [Make component link fields inline editable](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/make-component-link-fields-inline-editable)

In particular see the reference to 'Making subfields of embedded multivalue fields editable' section of the online documentation (login required):
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_531D916B066D4CD78661EB29BA33E2C3

Comment: We r not using Dreamweaver templating we r using c# templating for most of component template how we can achieve this in c# templating.should we have to create custom function to generate site edit tags around fields??

Comment: This is probably a great example of why to use Dreamweaver (or Razor) templates for 'front-end' content and not tangle this up in C#.  If you absolutely must do this in a C# template, then I would recommend that you just put a 'HTML comment placeholder' above your component field (in your existing C# TBB) and then replace this with the correct markup (or TCDL tag) in a separate Template Building Block.  This way, the code to replace will be in a single place (should it need to be tweaked) and it wouldn't break your HTML markup.

Comment: hi jonathan this is good idea can u please provide me all possible markup (TCDL Tag).

Comment: I would recommend checking the online documentation and the [Tridion UI 2012 functions for use in HTML templates](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates) Tridion Practice wiki post